# DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate How to add Image conditionally and hide checkbox in same column cell

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight

```
                      <c1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                          
                          <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="chkBxIsChecked" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                <Image Name="ErrorImage" Visibility ="{Binding IsImgVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" Source= "../../../Resources/Images/Fail.png" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="5,0,0,0"></Image>  
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                            <t:MapEventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestVM},Path=IsCkCommand}" CommandParameter="checked" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>

                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                            <t:MapEventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestVM},Path=IsCkCommand}" CommandParameter="unchecked" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </CheckBox>                                    
                            </DataTemplate>                                                                                            
                        </c1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                          
                    </c1:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image]
   I want to hide a check box in column  and display image based on the data from db .
   I was trying the above approach , but unable to display the image when i made visibility.collapse for the checkbox .
can i do that from codebehind ? , please suggest me .
Test one record in the attched image i am expecting to display image instead of checkbo ,where as it is showing empty because i made visibility collapsed against the row .

Thanks in advance .

[image: Here is the output i am getting from above code , i am expecting row 3 checkbox column should be displayed an image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added Image as child of CheckBox. So, making parent (CheckBox) collapsed will eventually make child (image) collapsed. ***Make checkBox and Image as siblings of parent container.***

Replace

```
<CheckBox>
   <Image/>
</CheckBox>
```

with

```
<Grid>
  <CheckBox/>
  <Image/>
<Grid>
```

*Assuming Visibility bindings working fine.*